# How can I tell who code signed an OS X app?

Tags: macos, codesign

On Windows, I can right-click a file and see who code signed it on the "Digital Signatures" tab of the Properties dialog. Is there a similar way to see which publisher signed an OS X app, or details about the certificate used to sign it?

I know I can run `codesign -d -r- appname.app` to see details about the certificate, and `codesign -vvvv appname.app` to see whether it passes validation, but neither of those shows me anything about the actual certificate or publisher who signed it, just the one in the bundle identifier for the app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

> $ codesign -dvvv the.app

And look to the `Authority` fields such as

`Authority=Adobe Systems, Incorporated`

However, apps distributed on the Mac App Store are all signed by Apple's certificate:

`Authority=Apple Mac OS Application Signing`

Answer (score 1):

There’s also a nice and free GUI utility called [RB App Checker Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/cz/app/rb-app-checker-lite/id519421117?mt=12):

[image: RB App Checker Lite screenshot]

Comment: No longer present in the app store, but direct link is https://brockerhoff.net/RB/AppCheckerLite/

Answer (score 0):

There is an app for that by the great Patrick Wardle:

> Verifying a file's cryptographic signature can deduce its origin or trustability. Unfortunately on macs there's no simple way to view a file's signature via the UI.
> What's Your Sign adds a menu item to Finder.app. Simply right-, or control-click on any file to display its cryptographic signing information!

Download at https://objective-see.org/products/whatsyoursign.html.